# Relaxing or relaxed

Tags: grammar

I have know that the 'ed' form of adjectives is used to describe feelings, and the 'ing' form is used to desribe things that make you have that feeling, but these examples from the Oxford dictionary make me confused

Some Oxford examples

1. This type of lighting creates a relaxing atmosphere.
2. A family-run hotel with a relaxed atmosphere
3. Candles and soft music create a relaxed environment.

Comment: "I have know that the 'ed' form of adjectives is used to describe feelings, and the 'ing' form is used to desribe things that make you have that feeling" <-- Do you believe that those forms are always used in those ways or only sometimes?

Answer (score 5):

I think *a relaxed atmosphere* is actually an example of [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), where the way you feel in the place is ascribed to the place. We do this a lot - we refer to a cheerful place, or a sad picture,

Comment: It's a pretty subtle distinction Colin but to me "relaxed atmosphere" (when describing a hotel) is more like saying "relaxed staff" or "relaxed manner" or "relaxed rules" or "relaxed engineering standards".  For me "relaxed staff" is like "tall staff" "overpaid staff" etc, and "relaxed atmosphere is arguably like that. For example, I could imagine saying "I can't relax at a hotel with a relaxed atmosphere, I prefer a orderly strict atmosphere so that I can feel relaxed."

Answer (score 4):

All those example sentences from Oxford are correct.

The rule you've heard about "ed" and "ing" adjectives is *not a rule of grammar*. It's a helpful *rule of thumb* for learners because it tends to be correct. In many languages, "ed" and "ing" adjectives are the same word, so it's difficult for English learners to know how to choose between them when forming sentences.

Like, imagine you want to complete this sentence:

> Are you having fun? You look ________ (boring/bored).

You can use this *rule of thumb* to correctly choose "bored". That's the only reason your teachers or English books say that.

When you try to apply this rule to all "ed" and "ing" adjectives, you run into problems because they aren't always feelings. Sometimes they have other meanings. "Relaxed", for example, *can be* a feeling, but not always.

> a relaxed atmosphere
> a relaxed environment

Clearly, an atmosphere or an environment cannot have feelings, so "relaxed" must not be a feeling. If we look [in a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relaxed), we can see that in both of these cases, "relaxed" probably means "informal" -- not an emotion.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I doubt any Brit would notice. A relaxing atmosphere makes you feel relaxed. Strictly one is describing the atmosphere, the other the feeling induced, but the one leads to the other.

> The hotel was described as having a relaxing atmosphere, but I didn't feel in the slightest relaxed, I was worrying about catching my flight in the morning.

Now we are truly differentiating.
A bit of 'advertising copy' describing the hotel would not really differentiate in the same way. A 'relaxed atmosphere' describes a hotel where the staff don't put any pressure on the guests. A 'relaxing atmosphere' might be one where the guests don't feel under any pressure. The difference is really so slight as to be almost indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

If something is "relaxing" then it helps you to relax. That is the only possible meaning of "relaxing atmosphere/environment".

However, "relaxed" can have another meaning, that of informality and lack of restrictions. For example, some events or places have an expectation that you dress or behave in a certain way, and others give you more licence to do as you please. We would describe the latter as "more relaxed", but that does not necessarily mean they are more relaxing. For example (from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relaxed))

> **(B2)** A relaxed situation or place is comfortable and informal:
> *It's a very friendly bar with a nice relaxed atmosphere.*

So if you mean the atmosphere helps you relax, it is clearer to say "relaxing".